# Checking if radiobuttonlist has been selected

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using this code to check if a radiobuttonlist has been selected, however it doesn't return false if nothing has been checked, and continues through to the function in the class behind. The radiobutton list is generated from databinding in codebehind.

```
<asp:LinkButton class="btn" id="linkDelete" runat="server" onclick="link_Delete" OnClientClick="checkform()">Delete Template</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:radiobuttonlist id="optMessageType" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="optMessageType_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatDirection="Vertical" CssClass="none-table">
</asp:radiobuttonlist>

function checkform() {
                var radiolist = document.getElementById('<%= optMessageType.ClientID %>');
                var radio = radiolist.getElementsByTagName("input");
                if (radio.length > 0) {
                    for (var x = 0; x < radio.length; x++) {
                        if (radio[x].type === "radio" && radio[x].checked) {
                            //alert("Checking...");
                            // alert("Selected item Value " + radio[x].value);
                            var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this template?")
                            if (r == true) {
                                //alert("You pressed OK!")
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                //alert("You pressed Cancel!");
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Select a template to delete");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    alert("nope");
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void link_Delete(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Label3.Text = "Deleted!"; //For Testing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
<asp:LinkButton class="btn" id="linkDelete" runat="server" onclick="link_Delete" OnClientClick="return checkform();">Delete Template</asp:LinkButton>
```

i have added `return` in `OnClientClick` atribute funcion call

hope this may solve our problem.

Comment: No that didn't do it.